# Azure AD B2C : User credential validation against custom user store

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

Can Azure AD B2C pass the "UserName/Email and Password" entered by end user to a third party trusted application for credentials validation and get the claims for the user on successful credentials validation by the App?
This scenario arises because, some of my users are in Azure AD B2C and some of the users are maintained in the custom user store and can't be moved to Azure AD B2C due to business reasons. Yet i want to provide same sign-in experience for both users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Wingtip sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c) contains an example of this integration.

See [the "ClassicAccount" claims provider](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/89b0c2e3f78605521e16d443a160fdbb0e5acca9/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L2272) for reference.

This claims provider, which is implemented by a REST API, is integrated in to the sign-in user journey to sign users in using logins that are external to the Azure AD B2C directory.

[Code for the REST API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipIdentityWebApplication) can be found in the same repository.

Comment: That helps. In this same scenario, are there any code samples available that obtains jwt access token from the third party trusted app mentioned above, by using the "token issuer" technical profile i.e 'remote token issuer service' as mentioned here in this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md#using-a-remote-token-issuer-service)